# Looping every single lines with readLine();

Tags: java, io

I am currently stuck with my current code of printing my file out with only 1 line of code in it. I am trying to loop through every single line with readLine() but uanble to achieve it. Stuck with looping either the first row or last row of line in the file.

The purpose of this is to print out exactly the same file with this program but printing it out as a folder with other different files.

```
try
{
    String sCurrentLine;

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testsample.csv"));

    if((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String info = br.readLine();
        resultString += sCurrentLine.toString();

    }
            this.WriteToFile(resultString);

}
```

Comment: Which version of java are you using ?
`import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
...
Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String info = br.readLine();
```

is not helping you. And you need while, not if

```
while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    resultString += sCurrentLine.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading only two lines. To read all lines you need `while` loop.

```
while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    //String info = br.readLine();- > Remove this line.
    resultString += sCurrentLine.toString();

}
```